# Dynamically re-creating a table layout

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I have a dynamic table layout created in OnCreate(). Everytime the activity resumes, the data in the table rows can change, so I would like to destroy the table rows and create new ones.
How can I do that? Thanks!!!

Here is what the OnCreate table creation portion looks like:

```
    tableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfVariables; i++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        tr.addView(cb);

        TextView dv = new TextView(this);
        tr.addView(dv);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        tr.addView(et);

        tl.addView(tr);
    }

    ll.addView(tl);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`tl.removeAllViews();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29), and then recreate the rows.